# Basic OOP concept in Perl

Tags: perl, oop

I'm learning the OOP concept in Perl where the syntax is different from Java, which I used to learn the OOP concept.

I have an example to declare a class `Person`, but I'm a bit confused.

The code is as follows

```
package Person;

sub new {

    my $class = shift;

    my $self  = {
        _firstName => shift,
        _lastName  => shift,
        _ssn       => shift,
    };

    # Print all the values just for clarification.

    print "First Name is $self->{_firstName}\n";
    print "Last Name is $self->{_lastName}\n";
    print "SSN is $self->{_ssn}\n";

    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
}
```

From the example above, is `my $self` a scalar variable or a hash variable?

As far as I know, hash variables in Perl are declared with `%` while `$` is used for scalar variables.

And what is the use of the `bless` function? Why does it return `$self`?

Comment: See also [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose) for more modern OO in Perl.

Comment: I suggest you watch this excellent tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKXvG6VKew4

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: *"your insistence on "arrays and hashes are not special" is just wrong"* I would respect that if you could find someone proficient with Perl who agreed with you. And I think you don't know what ***pedagogical*** means.

Comment: This is a big topic and is very well covered in [`perldoc perlootut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) which should be part of your Perl installation. You will need to be up to speed on the basics of Perl, such as references and anonymous data structures, but everything you need is described in `perldoc`. I have always used Perl to teach OOP because it provides Polymorphism, Inheritance, and Encapsulation using only the base language. Other languages make things "easier" by building everything into the syntax, but give much less insight into what is going on.

Comment: @simbabque: That video is a Moose tutorial, and I would expect it to confuse the OP even more. Perl is great on its own at bringing out that the object is just another parameter, and the "class" is just a namespace. Once you know all that, it's nice to have Moose create all the infrastructure for you, but I think it's essential to have an idea of what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the example above, is `my $self` a scalar variable or a hash variable?

`$self` is a scalar variable. You can tell that because it starts with a `$`.

(**Parenthetical update:** In the comments, brian points out that this rule is flawed. And he's right of course - as he usually is. The `$` at the start of `$self` shows that it's a scalar **value**, not a scalar **variable**. But if you take the `$` at the start together with the lack of look-up brackets - like `[...]` or `{...}` - following the variable name, then you can be sure this is a scalar variable.)

But your complete line of code is this:

```
my $self  = {
    _firstName => shift,
    _lastName  => shift,
    _ssn       => shift,
};
```

Here, the `{ ... }` is an "anonymous hash constructor". It creates a hash and returns a reference to it. References are always scalar values, so they can be stored in scalar variables (that's one of the major reasons for their existence).

So `$self` is still a scalar variable, but it contains a reference to a hash.

> And what is the use of the bless function?

The call to `bless()` effectively assign a type to the `$self` variable. Perl needs to know the type of your object in order to know which symbol table to search for the object's methods. When I'm running classes in this, I like to say that `bless()` is like writing the type of the object on a post-it note and slapping it on the object's forehead - so, later on, people can know what the type is.

> Why does it return $self?

You will call this method something like this:

```
my $person = Person->new(...); # passing various parameters
```

The `new()` method needs to return the newly created object in order that you can store it in a variable and manipulate it in some way later on.

But a Perl subroutine returns the value of the last expression in the subroutine, and `bless()` returns the "blessed" object, so it would be fine to end the subroutine with the previous line:

```
bless $self, $class;
```

But it's traditional to be more explicit about return values, so most people would add the `return` line. It makes for better documented code.

Comment: Not all things that start with a `$` are scalar variables. That's the wrong rule because people will see `$array[$i]`, apply your rule, and end up with the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$self` is a hash reference, so it's considered as a scalar in most manipulations.

`bless` is used to say that this hash reference is an object of the given class (which will be `Person` here unless you have child classe), so that you can call functions of this class using the `$object->function` notation.

And the `return $self` is necessary so you can actually retrieve the created object when you call `new`!

Comment: Nice, thanks for answering, but the $self variable still not clearly to be understand, is there any document I can refer to for more explanation?

Comment: @helloworld1234: I think you need to become more familiar with ordinary Perl before you start to study object-oriented programming. `my $self = { _firstName => shift, _lastName  => shift, _ssn  => shift }` is very ordinary Perl, and you must go there first.

Comment: *"`$self` is a hash reference, so it's considered as a scalar in most manipulations"* When is is not "considered as a scalar"?

Comment: *"And the return $self is necessary so you can actually retrieve the created object when you call new!"* No. The `new` subroutine would work fine if it ended at the `bless` line.